# Azure event-grid - How to handle the device status events

Tags: java, azure, device, azure-eventgrid

I have configured my devices and managing in Azure IoT Hub. I'm able to interact with my devices as expected. Now for handling the events like when device goes offline, automatically IoT hub should inform the back-end system about this.

While going through the Azure documentation, It has been mentioned that event-grids would be able to handle this. But I'm not getting any references on the same.

Can anyone provide me reference for this Implementation.

Comment: have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-event-grid and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-iot-hub

Comment: Thanks Roman, It helped me to get my things done.